# Magento2 staple error generation

Tags: magento2

I am getting the below error and i need to find out which class is causing this error.

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager, none given, called in
>   vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on
>   line 93 and defined in vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php on line
>   87

Not sure from where magento2 keeps generating this error. **Can anyone tell me from where magento2 generates this error?** In that case i can get the desired class from there.

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` may resolve this problem

Comment: Magento surely checks somewhere that all dependencies are not provided to a particular constructer or dependencies are not provided in order and then it generates this error. I need to know from where.